# IE strange border

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I noticed sometimes I see a grey border around the layout in IE.

I got also one on my site and it's a bit annoying.

Switching from IE8 to IE9 or otherwise sometimes makes this border disappear, but not on all sites.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it might happen?

[image]

Comment: Looks like browser chrome to me. What happens when you remove all the CSS?

Comment: It's not chrome. It's IE. Don't u see the Alexa toolbar?

Comment: By *browser chrome* he means the native browser frame, not the Chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I meant it looks like it's built into the browser UI and has nothing to do with the site you're viewing. I didn't realize how uncommon the term "[browser chrome](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/chrome.php)" was.

Comment: Ah, ok I understand now, it looks like a feature of IE8, or IE8 compat and below. Anyway you should make it an answer then.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty much a telltale sign that you're in Quirks Mode. Hit F12, and see what the Document Mode is listed as.

Then try to fix it. Make sure you have a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` as the first thing in your document, make sure your document is well-formed, and try sending the `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` header (or include it as a `<meta>` tag).

Comment: Lol, I'm not in quirks :) I would have spotted it. Gotta try your meta tag with edge though.

Comment: Well, I just tried to use '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />'  but I still do get this grey border in IE8 - I mean, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Any other ideas? Actually I even get the same thing on Youtube.com if I switch to IE8 Compat Mode.

Comment: I think it's default in IE8 actually. IE8 and below have that as part of the browser chrome, and you can't do anything about  it.